# Jquery multiple each function inside click event

Tags: jquery

When clicking the  I want this particular .parents ul to open and all other to collapse. Below code does not work for me.

I think I do not understand how I use **this** and misuse **e** in the below code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/der/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selected;
    $(".parents").click(function(){
        selected = this.id;

        // Open list
        $("#" + selected + " ul").css("display", "block");

        // Remember opened list
        $.cookie('tree', '#' + this.id);

        // Cycle through all lists
        $(".parents").each(function(e){
            // Collapse all children that does not
            // belongs to the opened list
            if(e.id != selected) {
                $("#" + e.id + " ul").css("display", "none");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.child_list {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="tree">
    <li class="parents" id="parent_1"><a href="#">Parent 1</a>
        <ul class="child_list">
            <li class="child"><a href="#">Child 1</a>
            <li class="child"><a href="#">Child 2</a>
            <li class="child"><a href="#">Child 3</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parents" id="parent_2"><a href="#">Parent 2</a>
        <ul class="child_list">
            <li class="child"><a href="#">Child 1</a>
            <li class="child"><a href="#">Child 2</a>
            <li class="child"><a href="#">Child 3</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of re-selecting things, find them relative to `this`, the item you clicked on, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $(".parents").click(function(){
    // Open list
    $(this).find("ul").show();

    // Remember opened list
    $.cookie('tree', '#' + this.id);

    // Cycle through all lists
    $(this).siblings().find("ul").hide();
  });
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/HQVmW/) (everything but cookie).  You could also give it a bit of animation by using [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) instead of [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/), [check that option here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/HQVmW/1/).

The above approach uses [tree traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/), so you start with the `<li>` you clicked on, then move around to find what you wanted, e.g. other [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to close their children, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$(".parents").each(function(e){
            // Collapse all children that does not
            // belongs to the opened list
            if(e.id != selected) {
                $("#" + e.id + " ul").css("display", "none");
            }
        });
```

to

```
$(".parents").each(function(){
            // Collapse all children that does not
            // belongs to the opened list
            id = $(this).attr('id');
            if(id != selected) {
                $("#" + id + " ul").css("display", "none");
            }
        });
```

`e` usually refers to an event but as  your only cycling elements there's no event there, so within each element you can use this instead.

Comment: The `<ul>` doesn't have an ID :)